# Checking if the given String has equally matching parenthesis

Tags: java

Found some interesting problem solving questions online and here it is.

```
You are to check the given String str if they contains matching parenthesis.
```

> **Example input:** [ ] , [ ( ] ) , { [ ] } , { [ } ] , { [ } ) , { ] }
>
> **Example output:** EQUAL, EQUAL, EQUAL, EQUAL, NOT EQUAL, NOT EQUAL

I have managed to complete the requirements for this feature using basics, just wondering if there is a better way of doing it?

```
String str = "{[(])}(){}";
    int pairs = 0;
    boolean unableToFind = false;
    ArrayList<Character> anChar = new ArrayList<Character>();

    for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {
        anChar.add(str.charAt(i));
    }

    if (str.length() % 2 == 0) { 
        while (pairs != str.length() / 2) {
            for (int i = 1; i < anChar.size(); i++) {
                char a = (char) anChar.get(0);
                char b = (char) anChar.get(i);
                if (a == '{' && b == '}' || a == '[' && b == ']' || a == '(' && b == ')') {
                    anChar.remove(i);
                    anChar.remove(0);
                    pairs++;
                    break;
                } else {
                    if (i == anChar.size() - 1) { // reached end of array
                        unableToFind = true;
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
            if (unableToFind)
                break;
        }

        if (pairs == str.length() / 2) {
            System.out.println("Log#01: The String have balanced parenthesis");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Log#02: The String do not have balanced parenthesis. (" + pairs + "/" + str.length() / 2 + " pairs found)");
        }
    } else {
        System.out.println("Log#03: The String do not have even numbers of parenthesis");
    }
```

Comment: This is probably better being asked on : http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on Code Review.

Comment: Generally, you use a stack for something like this. Simply iterate over the string. When you encounter an open-paren, push a token onto the stack, and pop when you encounter a close-paren. This is CS 102; there are many examples online.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your approach is overly complex. All you need is three counters - `countRound`, `countSquare`, and `countCurly`. Initialize all three to zero, then walk the string character-by-character. If you see an opening parentheses, increment its counter; if it is a closing parentheses, decrement its corresponding counter. Once the loop is over, all three counters must be at zero; otherwise the numbers of parentheses do not match up.

**Note:** This does *not* check that parentheses are balanced, because your example does not require it (i.e. `"[(])"` produces `"EQUAL"` even through the input is unbalanced).

Comment: I don't know if is a requirement, but I would put if the count got -1 is not equal, cause something close before to open.

Comment: @Rubico I wasn't sure of that myself, because OP's examples do not show or explain this situation. However, since balancing is not a requirement, I would suspect that counting is all there is to it.

Answer (score 3):

Just use a `Stack`. You need to go over each character in the String, and when you find a closing parenthesis, see if the top of the stack has the appropriate opening parenthesis. The logic would look something like this:

```
char c = input.charAt(i);
if(c == ')' || c == '}' || c == ']') {
    if(stack.isEmpty())
        return false;
    Character stackTop = stack.pop();
    if( (c == ')' && stackTop != '(') || 
        (c == '}' && stackTop != '{') || 
        (c == ']' &&  stackTop != '[') )
        return false;           
} else 
    stack.push(c);
```

For cases like "{{}", the stack will contain the first '{' at the end. So check to ensure if it's empty.

Not sure about the example you gave. If for "[ { ( ] } )", result is "EQUAL", *when the string clearly isn't balanced*, [dasblinkenlight](https://stackoverflow.com/users/335858/dasblinkenlight) has the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36056758/checking-if-the-given-string-has-equally-matching-parenthesis/36056950#36056950) :)

Comment: implementation could be better. but the datastructure choice is good for +1

Comment: @Kent Yes, sir. I realized as I was writing it. Laziness took over. :p

Comment: can you please update the answer with complete solution?

Comment: @saikumarm I was thinking along the lines of offloading to a function, that checks if a pair(top of stack and the current character) is a valid pair (using class constants). Do you think that is a good idea?

Comment: @Kent I just added a comment regarding the other alternative I had in mind. If this isn't an implementation you were thinking about, maybe we could work together to come up with something good?

Answer (score 1):

Not as Elegant as the previous answers but it works.
Check if the count in for pair of brackets match.

```
public class EqualClass {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String input = "[ ] , [ ( ] ) , { [ ] } , { [ } ] , { [ } ) , { ] }";
        String[] tokens = input.split(",");

        char[] bracketTypes = { '[', '{', '(' };
        char[] oppositeBracketType = { ']', '}', ')' };

        for (String token : tokens) {
            boolean equal = true;
            char[] characters = token.toCharArray();
            for (int indx = 0; indx < bracketTypes.length; indx++) {
                if (EqualClass.Test(characters, bracketTypes[indx]) != EqualClass
                                .Test(characters, oppositeBracketType[indx])) {
                    equal = false;
                    break;
                }

            }

            if (!equal) {
                System.out.println(token + " Not Equal");
            } else {
                System.out.println(token + " Equal");
            }

        }
    }

    public static int Test(char[] tokenOfCharacter, char bracketType) {
        int count = 0;
        for (char character : tokenOfCharacter) {
            if (character == bracketType) {
                count += 1;
            }
        }
        return count;
    }

}
```