# finding strings with valid {}()[]

Tags: java, hashmap, stack

How can I fix my code so that it can find the valid (){}[]? For now, it just returns true.

```
public static boolean isValid(String s){

        HashMap<Character, Character> specialChar= new HashMap<>();
        specialChar.put('{', '}');
        specialChar.put('[',']');
        specialChar.put('(',')');
        Stack<Character> stk = new Stack<>();
        for (int i=0; i<s.length(); i++){

            if (specialChar.keySet().contains(s.charAt(i))){
                stk.push(s.charAt(i));
            }
            else if (specialChar.values().contains(s.charAt(i))){
                if (!stk.empty()) {
                    stk.pop();
                }
            }

        }

        return stk.isEmpty();

    }


 System.out.println(isValid("{}{lll}]"));
```

Comment: Can you post what `s` is?

Comment: In what sense are the `(){}[]` valid or invalid?

Comment: Counting brackets is very easy, you need to have a `Map<Something, Integer>`. When you find the opening bracket, increment; when you find a closing bracket, decrement. If a count is ever below zero, you have an issue - otherwise, all counts should be `0` at the end. The `Something` is something that allows you to lookup bracket type.

Comment: [{}]() is valid ][{} not valid {}{ not valid

Comment: P.S., don't use `Stack`.

Comment: I don't think a map is really needed. Three counters for each type of bracket are enough

Comment: @BoristheSpider not really following your solution. mind writing it as an answer?

Comment: @RoyalBg three counters, possibly in a `Map`...

Comment: @MonaJalal what about `[{]}`?

Comment: @MonaJalal this smells an awful lot like homework - so the rest is up to you.

Comment: When you find a closing delimiter, you fail to check whether the stack is already empty (if it is, then your string is invalid).  If the stack is nonempty, then you fail to check whether the opening delimiter you pop from it in fact matches the closing delimiter you found.

Comment: I am not sure if the person who would ask me this question in the future would consider it valid or not but I personally won't count [{]} as valid

Comment: @AndyTurner my solution below considers [{]} as false

Comment: @MonaJalal true, but it also considers `[]` as false, which I don't think is what you intend.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Checking if the given String has equally matching parenthesis](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36056758/checking-if-the-given-string-has-equally-matching-parenthesis)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I made this method a while back as it was a question on codewars.com

You have 4 conditions in which you need to return `false`.

Closing brace on an empty `Stack`

Closing `)` and top `Character` in `Stack` is not `(`

Closing `}` and top `Character` in `Stack` is not `{`

Closing `]` and top `Character` in `Stack` is not `[`

```
public static boolean isValid(String s) {
    System.out.println(s);
    Stack<Character> st = new Stack<>();

    for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
        char ch = s.charAt(i);
        if (ch == '(' || ch == '{' || ch == '[') {
            st.push(ch);
        } else if (ch == ')' || ch == '}' || ch == ']') {
            if (st.isEmpty()) {
                return false;
            }
            char topChar = st.pop();
            if (ch == ')' && topChar != '(') {
                return false;
            }
            if (ch == '}' && topChar != '{') {
                return false;
            }
            if (ch == ']' && topChar != '[') {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
    return st.isEmpty();
}
```

Running

```
System.out.println(isValid("{}{lll}]"));
```

Yields in:

> {}{lll}]
>   false

Comment: Nice solution. Not sure why my thoughts were guided towards using hashmap besides stack

Comment: You may as well just use `char topChar = st.pop();`, since you either `pop()` or `return false;` - no need to `peek` separately. Also, I would use `s.charAt(i)` rather than `s.toCharArray()`, since the latter copies the string into a new `char[]`.

Comment: @AndyTurner, thanks, that is more logical. I incorporated your comment.

Answer (score 2):

This seems as an interview question, or so it does, back in the times I was going to junior interviews.

You do have fixed size of bracket types - three `[]`, `{}`, `()`, so it's enough to keep three counters for each e.g. `indexers`, `curlies` and `normals`. At the beginning they are normalized - `0` for each.

Then you traverse the string char by char. For each char, check the bracket type and increment the respective counter if it's an opening one, or decrement if it's a closing one. Once you reach a negative counter, it means you have reached a closing one, after they were normalized, let's say `{} {} }`, so you just return `false`. It's an unrecoverable error, you cannot open an already closed bracket.

```
while (indexers >= 0 && curlies >= 0 && normals >= 0) {
    if (char == '}') curlies--;
    if (char == '{') curlies++
    if (char == ')') normals--;
    // ...
}
```

The main point is after loop finished, all of the counters to be zero :-)

Comment: yes, I am trying to prepare for interviews (as a new college grad)

Comment: Obviously this passes `[{]}`, which may or may not be desired.

Comment: This won't work. It will validate e.g. '({)}' too.

Comment: Which could be OK, depends on the task.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static boolean isValid(String s){

        HashMap<Character, Character> specialChar= new HashMap<>();
        specialChar.put('{', '}');
        specialChar.put('[',']');
        specialChar.put('(',')');
        Stack<Character> stk = new Stack<>();
        for (int i=0; i<s.length(); i++){

            if (specialChar.keySet().contains(s.charAt(i))){
                stk.push(s.charAt(i));
            }
            else if (specialChar.values().contains(s.charAt(i))){
                if (!stk.empty() && stk.peek()==s.charAt(i)) {
                    stk.pop();
                }
                else return false;
            }

        }

        return stk.isEmpty();

    }
```

Feel free to provide feedback, comment, etc!

Comment: This doesn't quite work, for instance `isValid("[]")` returns false. For this to work, you'd need to push `specialChar.get(s.charAt(i))` in the "opening bracket" condition. Can you think why?

Comment: Or in the comparison, use specalChar.get (stk.peek ())

Comment: i'll get back to my answer later with some modification. Thanks for the feedback

Comment: @greyfairer yep, that'd work too.

Answer (score 0):

```
   /**
     * Validate if there balanced brackets in String 
     *
     * @param s is the string to be validated
     * @return true, if is valid
     */

    public static boolean isValid(String s)
    {
        /* wrong use of map (because you never said "get value of this key") here, 
         * may be you can create two Set here
         */
        Map<Character, Character> specialChar= new HashMap<Character, Character>(3);
        specialChar.put('{','}');
        specialChar.put('[',']');
        specialChar.put('(',')');

        Stack<Character> stk = new Stack<Character>();
        for (int i=0; i<s.length(); i++)
        {
            char c=s.charAt(i);
            if (specialChar.keySet().contains(c))
            {
                stk.push(s.charAt(i));
            }
            else if (specialChar.values().contains(c))
            {
                //use equals(),should not use use ==, which works but not right way to do 
                if (stk.isEmpty() || stk.pop().equals(c)) 
                {
                    return false;
                }

            }

        }

        return stk.isEmpty();
    }
```